Apache Spark multiple servers in docker
Dear apache spark community,
I would like to ask some question.
My questions:

From apache spark 3.4 onwards, there is new design remote connect, what is the difference between master? Is this utilized all the existing worker, I could not find any docs about this.
When we using SparkSession.builder.master(...) in server B, do we also need to have spark ready on server B?


Background: a server A hosted a spark cluster with master and multiple worker. server B try to access server A's spark cluster with python IDE
Note: server B does not have anything about spark, Only pyspark installed!

I have two case to show:
Case 1: In server B, i can connect to server A using remote connect in IDE like:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark_master_url = "sc://ServerA_IP_ADDRESS:15002"
spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName('test') \
.remote(spark_master_url) \
.getOrCreate()

This one working perfectly fine!

Case 2: In server B, i try to connect to server A using master connect in IDE like:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark_master_url = "spark://ServerA_IP_ADDRESS:7077"
spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName('test') \
.master(spark_master_url) \
.getOrCreate()

I got this issue when running this code:
WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources


My yaml file (from: https://medium.com/@yssmelo/spark-connect-launch-spark-applications-anywhere-with-the-client-server-architecture-dbt-f99399c566fe):
version: '3'

services:
  spark-master:
    image: apache/spark:3.5.1
    container_name: spark-master
    hostname: spark-master
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    environment:
      - SPARK_MASTER_HOST=spark-master
      - SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
      - SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8080
    entrypoint: 
      - "bash"
      - "-c"
      - "/opt/spark/sbin/start-master.sh && tail -f /dev/null"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/opt/spark/work-dir/spark-warehouse/data:rw

  spark-connect:
    image: apache/spark:3.5.1
    container_name: spark-connect
    hostname: spark-connect
    ports:
      - "4040:4040"
      - "15002:15002"
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    volumes:
      - ./jars/spark-connect_2.12-3.5.1.jar:/opt/spark/jars/spark-connect_2.12-3.5.1.jar
      - ./data:/opt/spark/work-dir/spark-warehouse/data:rw
    command: 
      - "bash"
      - "-c"
      - "/opt/spark/sbin/start-connect-server.sh --jars /opt/spark/jars/spark-connect_2.12-3.5.1.jar && tail -f /dev/null"

  spark-worker:
    image: apache/spark:3.5.1
    container_name: spark-worker
    hostname: spark-worker
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    entrypoint:
      - "bash" 
      - "-c"
      - "/opt/spark/sbin/start-worker.sh spark://spark-master:7077 && tail -f /dev/null"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/opt/spark/work-dir/spark-warehouse/data:rw

